# Angular 9 a for loop is adding a value to an empty property name

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, for-loop

I am iterating over an array of object where inside each object I need to add a new property with a certain value. The `keyFieldAttribute` is selected from a drop down list:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      console.log('KeyFieldAttr: ', keyFieldAttribute, this.getInitialOdkDataArray[i][keyField]);
      data[i][keyFieldAttribute] = this.getInitialOdkDataArray[i][keyField];
      console.log(data[i]);
}
```

At the `console.log('KeyFieldAttr: ', keyFieldAttribute, this.getInitialOdkDataArray[i][keyField]);` I can clearly see the `keyFieldAttribute` and the value that should be assigned to.

At `console.log(data[i]);` I cannot see the name of property but it got a value. It is like:

`"": some_value`

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is a sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fvnsgs) which is working but not working on my project.

Comment: Try to use map function on array
like this.array = this.array.map(item => { item['test'] = 'All'; return item})

Comment: how is `keyFieldAttribute` getting its value? is it set from promise/observable?

Comment: It is from a reactive form control. As you can see it is consoled (underlined in red). @Andrei